# Sparrow chart swipe event define

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sparrow-framework

> I have a sparrow chart on wp8 and I want to define the swipe gesture to scrol on the grapf.Swipe on the wright, the graph shows me previous entrys.My swipe showld scroll in graph. Can anyone help me? or provide me some ideeas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you are describing is called panning.

The sparrow chart control does not support panning by itself. However this link 
[Zooming and panning sparrow chart](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/445298)
Shows you how to do it using sliders and the zoomoffset and zoomcoefficient attributes.

Now you have the problem of having to use a slider. What I did was place the slider on top of the chart and set its opacity to 0. Now it looks as if you are manipulating the chart but what you are actually manipulating is the slider. Hope this helps.